# Как найти количество вариантов получения числа из последовательности чисел

Tags: комбинаторика

Дана последовательность чисел. Например: 2 9 3 6 3 8 1 10 6 7.

Нужно узнать: сколькими способами можно образовать число, большее 8.

Правильные ответ - 42, но я никак не могу понять как его добиться.

Подскажите формулу или толкните в нужном направлении.

Comment: Какова методика образования этого нового числа? Сложением двух?

Comment: если мы уже добились того, что комбинация больше 8 (3+3+3=9), то дополнять комбинацию новыми числами уже нельзя (3+3+3+5 - нельзя, ведь 3+3+3 - уже > 8).

Comment: Это задача скорее не на комбинаторику, а на динамическое программирование.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что правильно понял задачу, поскольку у меня на данной последовательности чисел 42 не получается. Но ответ на всякий случай напишу.

Общая идея моего алгоритма состоит в том, чтобы пройти в цикле всю последовательность, уходя в рекурсию на её оставшуюся часть всякий раз, когда текущий элемент не завершает собой очередную комбинацию. Если же текущий элемент оказывается завершающим, то к промежуточному итогу прибавляется единица. Каждый рекурсивный вызов возвращает свой промежуточный итог, который прибавляется к промежуточному итогу более высокого уровня. И в конце объединение промежуточных итогов первого уровня даёт общее количество комбинаций.

На Python'е это выглядит вот так:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

numbers = [2, 9, 3, 6, 3, 8, 1, 10, 6, 7]

def combinations(selected=[], nexts=numbers):
    subtotal = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(nexts):
        if sum(selected) + n > 8:
            # print selected+[n]
            subtotal += 1
        else:
            subtotal += combinations(selected+[n], nexts[i+1:])
    return subtotal

print combinations()
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже придумал элегантное и простое решение. Оно основывается на предположении, что все комбинации которые вы ищете являются подмножеством разбиений максимального элемента исходного массива. (Не знаю как точно это доказать, но интуитивно это похоже на правду).

1. Ищем максимальный элемент в исходном массиве.
2. Генерируем все его (макисмального элемента) [разбиения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) каким-нибудь готовым алгоритмом.
3. Проверяем каждое разбиение на наличие элементов из исходного массива. Если там встречаются элементы которых нет в массиве, удаляем разбиение из списка.
   Если в нем встречаются повторы или оно слишком длинное тоже удаляем.
4. Считаем оставшиеся валидные разбиения в списке - *это и есть ответ*.

Comment: а вдруг там будет int_max? и зачем нужно его разбиения? Учитывая, что уже p(1000) ≈ 2.4 × 10^31

Comment: Да и еще похоже это предположение неверно для каких-нибудь массивов вида 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 20. Как оказалось это не очень хороший вариант.

Comment: Но идея о том, чтобы сгенерировать какое-нибудь надмножество из исходного массива и потом обрезать его все равно может оказаться полезной, так что не буду удалять ответ пока.

Comment: Разбиения с повторами нельзя просто так удалять. Например, разбиение {3, 3} нужно удалять только тогда, когда в исходном массиве нет двух троек. Если есть ровно две, то его нужно просто учесть. Если есть три, то учесть трижды. Если есть четыре, то учесть шесть раз. И так далее...